# Как объединить два (click) запроса в angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Нужно избавиться от повторения клика в скрипте ниже.

```
<img 
    type="button" 
    class="px-2" 
    src="/assets/images/svg/edit.svg" 
    alt="no icon"
                      
    (click)="activeIndex = inx" 
    (click)="editTopic = true"
>
```

Comment: Добавьте функцию и вызывайте ее на клик

Comment: Тоже думал так сделать. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: можно через `;` - `activeIndex = inx; editTopic = true`, но я согласен с мнением, что логику стоит держать в методе, в не шаблоне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе компонента нужно сделать метод, который будет обрабатывать вашу логику.

```
imageClick(index: number) {
  this.activeIndex = index;
  this.editTopic = true;
}
```

И вызвать этот метод через `click`

```
<img type="button" (click)="imageClick(inx)">
```

P.S. Желательно всю логику шаблона помещать в методы. Так вся логика будет в одном месте, а также ее будет легко доработать и расширить при необходимости.